# Unable to Deploy Allure report on Jetty server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, maven-jetty-plugin, jetty-9, allure, jetty-8

I am trying to deploy allure report which was generated after "mvn clean test site". I have used mvn jetty:run and when I tried to open "http://localhost:8080", I got a "Directory:/" as a text in firefox browser instead of actual Allure report.

[Output of jetty server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Ytm.jpg)

### Error Section

No Error

## pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycomp</groupId>
    <artifactId>AllureWebDriverMvnProj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <allure.version>1.5.0-RC1</allure.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.7</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.stqa.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdriver-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/target/site</directory>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/target/allure-results</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng_demo.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>

                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configuration>
                        <webAppSourceDirectory>../AllureWebDriverMvnProj/target/site/allure-maven-plugin/</webAppSourceDirectory>
                        <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                        <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
                    </configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <!-- profiles -->
    <profiles>
        <!-- browsers -->
        <profile>
            <id>firefox</id>
            <properties>
                <capabilities>/firefox.capabilities</capabilities>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>chrome</id>
            <properties>
                <capabilities>/chrome.capabilities</capabilities>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ie</id>
            <properties>
                <capabilities>/ie.capabilities</capabilities>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>safari</id>
            <properties>
                <capabilities>/safari.capabilities</capabilities>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>phantomjs</id>
            <properties>
                <capabilities>/phantomjs.capabilities</capabilities>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>opera</id>
            <properties>
                <capabilities>/opera.capabilities</capabilities>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>htmlunit</id>
            <properties>
                <capabilities>/htmlunit.capabilities</capabilities>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- environments -->
        <profile>
            <id>localhost</id>
            <properties>
                <site.url>http://localhost/</site.url>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>devhost</id>
            <properties>
                <site.url>http://devhost/</site.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>testhost</id>
            <properties>
                <site.url>http://testhost/</site.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prodhost</id>
            <properties>
                <site.url>http://prodhost.com/</site.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- grid -->
        <profile>
            <id>nogrid</id>
            <properties>
                <grid.url></grid.url>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>grid</id>
            <properties>
                <grid.url>http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/</grid.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

## Console Output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AllureWebDriverMvnProj 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.11.v20150529:run (default-cli) @ AllureWebDriverMvnProj >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ AllureWebDriverMvnProj ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ AllureWebDriverMvnProj ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ AllureWebDriverMvnProj ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 11 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ AllureWebDriverMvnProj ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.11.v20150529:run (default-cli) @ AllureWebDriverMvnProj <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.11.v20150529:run (default-cli) @ AllureWebDriverMvnProj ---
2015-11-10 13:38:35.132:INFO::main: Logging initialized @9160ms
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: AllureWebDriverMvnProj
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src\main\webapp
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory E:\Selenium\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32\Luna_Workspace_new\AllureWebDriverMvnProj\src\main\webapp does not exist. Trying E:\Selenium\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32\Luna_Workspace_new\AllureWebDriverMvnProj\target\webapp-tmp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = E:\Selenium\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32\Luna_Workspace_new\AllureWebDriverMvnProj\target\classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = E:\Selenium\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32\Luna_Workspace_new\AllureWebDriverMvnProj\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = null
[INFO] Webapp directory = E:\Selenium\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32\Luna_Workspace_new\AllureWebDriverMvnProj\target\webapp-tmp
2015-11-10 13:38:35.337:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.11.v20150529
2015-11-10 13:38:42.450:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@7d29df{/,file:/E:/Selenium/eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32/Luna_Workspace_new/AllureWebDriverMvnProj/target/webapp-tmp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/E:/Selenium/eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32/Luna_Workspace_new/AllureWebDriverMvnProj/target/webapp-tmp/}
2015-11-10 13:38:42.466:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
2015-11-10 13:38:42.592:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5cd81a{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}[INFO] Started Jetty Server

2015-11-10 13:38:42.592:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @16620ms
```

Comment: This issue has stopped all my work. Someone please help to resolve the issue  :(

Answer (score 1):

In maven test and site are different phases.
You should run maven commands in two steps:
1. mvn clean test
2. mvn site
Then you will get generated Allure report

Answer (score 1):

@Illia B, Thanks for the reply. We can mention "site" along with the "clean test". Its gonna work smoothly. The issue was with the  configuration tag (By mistakenly I mentioned it twice) and the webAppSourceDirectory tag was pointing at wrong directory.
    I targeted it to the right path and it worked.