# Not able to view Allure report on Jetty server

Tags: maven, testng, allure

I am trying to set up Allure reports in my automation project. I am following - https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/TestNG, but the http://localhost:8080 only shows "Directory: /" text. I also found [Unable to Deploy Allure report on Jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626654/unable-to-deploy-allure-report-on-jetty-server) had the same problem but the solution there didn't help.

Comment: Here is the [pom.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2kK0Mk0C_6US1lOcHpuZEs4TUk)

Comment: This is the output I get on running [mvn site](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2kK0Mk0C_6UZWhrNndwRkpJb2s)

Comment: Use [edit] to provide additional information and include the files directly in your question instead of linking to an external hoster.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung thanks for the info, I couldn't find how to edit after posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have wrong site path for jetty, try to change jetty parameter from:

`<webAppSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>`
to

`<webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>`